# Use gruntjs as precommit hook

Tags: git, gruntjs, pre-commit-hook

Is there a way to run a gruntjs task as precommit hook. For example I want do prevent commits with failing tests or jshint issues. I've also think about to run a code beautifier for every commit.

Comment: yes; but you need node on the machine where this runs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git hooks are just scripts executed when you do an action like commit. They can contain whatever programming language you'd like.

Example of triggering grunt:

```
#!/bin/sh
grunt
```

Save this in the file: `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

If grunt exits with an error code higher than 0, which it does if any task fail, it will prevent the commit:

> Exiting non-zero from this hook aborts the commit

---

Reading material: [Tips for using a git pre-commit hook](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/)

And the git docs: [8.3 Customizing Git - Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

> Like many other Version Control Systems, Git has a way to fire off custom scripts when certain important actions occur.

Comment: Dont' forget to do chmod +x on your pre-commit file

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the same issue and detailed a more comprehensive Grunt solution on http://viget.com/extend/grunt-getting-started-with-git-hooks

Comment: You can also do this really easily now (sans Grunt, if you like) using Husky: https://github.com/typicode/husky

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out [grunt-githooks](http://rhumaric.com/2013/11/introducing-grunt-githooks/), a nice Grunt plugin that does all the magic for you and lets you easily register Grunt tasks for certain hooks from within your `Gruntfile.js`, such as:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  githooks: {
    all: {
      // Will run the jshint and test:unit tasks at every commit
      'pre-commit': 'jshint test:unit',
    }
  }
});
```

(Taken from the docs at https://github.com/wecodemore/grunt-githooks#defining-a-few-hooks)

Find the module on npm [here](https://github.com/wecodemore/grunt-githooks).