# TortoiseSVN Client/Grunt: Hook a grunt task to TortoiseSVN client

Tags: gruntjs, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to hook a Grunt task at TortoiseSVN client? In our UI project managed by Grunt, we would like to hook some of the Grunt tasks such as Jslint, code formatter, etc to the TortoiseSVN commit operation.

The idea is to prevent commit operation on unhealthy code.

Comment: Please refer to this discussion. However this one is for Git

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212939/use-gruntjs-as-precommit-hook <br/> Refer this project https://github.com/dsheiko/jscodesniffer#a-svn

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at pre-commit hooks.

> Your Subversion repository already has some template hook scripts. For
>   example, the pre-commit template is in
>   PATH_TO_REPOS/hooks/pre-commit.tmpl. These templates contain
>   instructions on what the hook script does and what parameters it can
>   expect.

```
su - svn                      # As user svn
cd PATH_TO_REPOS/hooks        # Change to the hooks directory
cp pre-commit.tmpl pre-commit # Create a pre-commit script
emacs pre-commit              # Edit to taste
chmod u+x pre-commit          # It needs to be executable
```

Source: http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook

In your pre-commit hook, simply call the desired grunt tasks

```
grunt lint test
```